# Predefined Character Classes regex match fails when using CANON_EQ

Tags: java, regex

I added code to support Unicode Canonical Equivalence in Regex. However, when I use a precomposed character and one of the Predefined Character Class character like \s, the match seems to fail.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Pattern withCE = Pattern.compile("^a\u030A\\sx$",Pattern.CANON_EQ);
        Pattern withoutCE = Pattern.compile("^a\u030A\\sx$");
        String inputWithCE = "\u00E5 x";
        String inputWithoutCE = "a\u030A x";

        System.out.println("Matches with canon eq: " + withCE.matcher(inputWithCE).matches());
        System.out.println("Matches without canon eq: " + withoutCE.matcher(inputWithoutCE).matches());
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
Matches with canon eq: false
Matches without canon eq: true
```

Try it here: https://ideone.com/vBzzL2

I was expecting the result to be 'true' even when used with canonical equivalence option to compile the regex pattern. What am I doing wrong

Comment: It works with Java 9+

Comment: I tested with Amazon Corretto 11 and it works as per @Andreas suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in Java 9.

You can try it out:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java8_online.php

```
Matches with canon eq: false
Matches without canon eq: true
```

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_java_compiler.php

```
Matches with canon eq: true
Matches without canon eq: true
```